# Use MultiPointTouchArea to open a page

Tags: qt, qml

I use MutiPointTouchArea to open a page , the user can use three-fingers to operate a pull-down action to open the page.
But, when the page successfully opened, it **need user to click the page first** to **activate** the page before they can operate the page, (**just like the page is sleeping,need a click to activate**)

This  is my code:

```
MultiPointTouchArea {
    id: mpArea
    z: 10
    anchors.fill: parent
    mouseEnabled: false
    maximumTouchPoints: 3
    minimumTouchPoints: 1

    property bool trigged: false

    onTouchUpdated: {
        if (touchPoints.length === 3) {
            if ((touchPoints[0].startY < 50 && touchPoints[0].y > 150)
                && (touchPoints[1].startY < 50 && touchPoints[1].y > 150)
                && (touchPoints[2].startY < 50 && touchPoints[2].y > 150)) {
                    openAdminPage()    //open page here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it MutiPointTouchArea's bug? because **if I use a button rather than this gesture to open the page, everything works fine**, user can operate the page as soon as the page opened, no need to click first.

Comment: Does `Component.onCompleted: page.forceActiveFocus()` help? or, even `mp.forceActiveFocus()` ?

Comment: @StephenQuan both can't help, i even set 'z = 999' but nothing changed

Comment: can you include in your question (1) the version of Qt, (2) the device you've tried? (particularly the OS). I am curious to try and this info will help me recreate the scenario. Also would help is a mock minimal repro app, as, I would need that to recompile and run.